# DropQueue mechanism for RX.net

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, system.reactive, reactive-programming, reactive

I came across a back pressure issue with RX.net I can't find a solution for. I have an observable real-time stream of log messages.

```
var logObservable = /* Observable stream of log messages */
```

Which I want to expose via a TCP interface which serializes the real-time log messages from the `logObservable` before they are sent over the wire. So I do the following:

```
foreach (var message in logObservable.ToEnumerable())
{
   // 1. Serialize message
   // 2. Send it over the wire. 
}
```

The problem arises with the `.ToEnumerable()` if a back pressure scenario happens e.g. if the client on the other end pauses the stream. The problem is that `.ToEnumerable()` caches the items which result in a lot of memory usage. I'm looking for a mechanism something like a `DropQueue` which only buffers, let say, the last 10 messages e.g.

```
var observableStream = logObservable.DropQueue(10).ToEnumerable();
```

Is this the right way to way to solve this issue? And do you know to implement such a mechanism to avoid possible back pressure issue?

Comment: `.take(10).toenumerable()?` would work wouldn't it?

Comment: I want a continuous stream of log messages over the wire. If I do as you propose will it not only take 10 log messages and then complete the observable stream? The issue I'm trying to solve is if the clients are too slow to retrieve the log messages or pauses the stream it should only cache e.g. 10 items instead of an unbounded number of items.

Comment: What about `.Throttle(...)` or `.Sample(..)`?

Comment: @Enigmativity: I would like to avoid `.Throttle()` or `.Sample()` if the client can keep up. The case I'm trying to cover is if the client decides to e.g. to pause the stream then it shouldn't cache the items. I found the operators `.Next()` and `.Latest()` which maybe could be used instead of `.ToEnumerable()` but I can't find adequate documentation for them.

Comment: After some more research, I found a marble diagram on https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/59, and it seems like a can use. `Latest()` which would be similar to `.DropQueue(1)`.

They write: "For `Latest`, the next of Iterator will check if there is a cached value, if so, returns the cached value, and deleted the cached value. If there is not a cached value, it will blocks until the next value is emitted from the Observable, and returns it.

Comment: To my understanding, this means that if I have a fast producer and a slow consumer it will throw away values and only return the latest value if the consumer can't keep up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `DropQueue` implementation:

```
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> ToDropQueue<TSource>(
        this IObservable<TSource> source,
        int queueSize,
        Action backPressureNotification = null,
        CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var queue = new BlockingCollection<TSource>(new ConcurrentQueue<TSource>(), queueSize);
        var isBackPressureNotified = false;

        var subscription = source.Subscribe(
            item =>
            {
                var isBackPressure = queue.Count == queue.BoundedCapacity;

                if (isBackPressure)
                {
                    queue.Take(); // Dequeue an item to make space for the next one

                    // Fire back-pressure notification if defined
                    if (!isBackPressureNotified && backPressureNotification != null)
                    {
                        backPressureNotification();
                        isBackPressureNotified = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    isBackPressureNotified = false;
                }

                queue.Add(item);
            },
            exception => queue.CompleteAdding(),
            () => queue.CompleteAdding());

        token.Register(() => { subscription.Dispose(); });

        using (new CompositeDisposable(subscription, queue))
        {
            foreach (var item in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
```